# Make a recurring long event every year in FullCalendar v5

Tags: javascript, events, fullcalendar, recurring

I'm struggling to create a recurring long event every year using fullcalendar v5. Let's say for example I want to create an event starting on December 15th and running until December 31st, and have it repeated every year. How do I achieve this? I've found solutions for recurring event every week and month on the "simple recurrence" section of the documentation, but no examples for a yearly basis recurrence. If you could provide a simple example that would be great. Thanks a lot in advance and regards.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `I've found solutions for recurring event every week and month on the "simple recurrence" section`... as far as I can see it only supports daily and weekly recurrence, not monthly?

Comment: But anyway, as it says on that very same page, if you want something more complex you can use the RRule integration provided by fullCalendar. There is then a link to the documentation about that. And there are more than enough examples of RRule online that you can make an attempt at this yourself before you need to ask.